# Is a hired non-Jewish maid prohibited to work on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, aseres-hadibros

I am trying to understand what is meant by [Devarim 5:14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14085&st=&pgnum=76). It says that your slave may not perform any *melacha* so that they "may rest as you do".

Does this mean that if someone has a full-time live-in maid who cleans the dishes and cooks and watches the children among other tasks - does this mean that the maid has a complete day off and is forbidden to do any of these things? I understand that a maid who is paid is not the same as an unpaid slave. But why would payment, alone, be a factor in changing the status? In both cases, the person is still working for you. Would it matter if the maid is unpaid and is volunteering her time or is "bartering" by having free rent and food?

Comment: In any case, it would also be a matter of *amira leakum*. It would have nothing to do with the restrictions of an eved. An eved is chayav like a women and would be unable to violate any mitzvos like cooking on Shabbos in any event.

Comment: You can't have them do *melacha*, but they (like Jewish hired help) can watch kids, set the table, or the like.

Comment: 2 reasons might be she  is not yours and she is not doing the work for you but for the money

Comment: A Jew is not obligated to feed his non Jewish slave.

Comment: She's not forbidden from doing anything at all (except resting on _Shabas_ and the _mitzvos b'ne Noach_).

Comment: " In both cases, the person is still working for you. " Your making an assumption that the problem of a slave working is that the person is working for you; the Torah says no such thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title and your "thoughts" in the body are unrelated.

**Slaves** are your property and your responsibility - and somewhat Jewish - and it's your responsibility to ensure they keep Shabbat. (Like your kids).

See [סימן דש - על איזה עבד מצוה על שביתתו](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_25.html#HtmpReportNum0062_L2) for details. Depends on how "Jewish" he is.

> **אָדָם מְצֻוֶּה עַל שְׁבִיתַת עַבְדּוֹ** שֶׁמָּל וְטָבַל לְשֵׁם עַבְדוּת וְקִבֵּל עָלָיו מִצְווֹת הַנּוֹהֲגוֹת בְּעֶבֶד, אֲבָל אִם לֹא מָל וְטָבַל אֶלָּא קִבֵּל עָלָיו שֶׁבַע מִצְווֹת בְּנֵי נֹחַ, הֲרֵי הוּא כְּגֵר תּוֹשָׁב וּמֻתָּר לַעֲשׂוֹת מְלָאכָה בְּשַׁבָּת  לְעַצְמוֹ, אֲבָל לֹא  לְרַבּוֹ; וְאָסוּר לְכָל יִשְׂרָאֵל לוֹמַר לוֹ לַעֲשׂוֹת מְלָאכָה בְּשַׁבָּת לְצֹרֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל, אֲפִלּוּ מִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַבּוֹ. וְאִם לֹא קִבֵּל עָלָיו שׁוּם מִצְוָה אֶלָּא עֲדַיִן הוּא עַכּוּ''ם גָּמוּר דִּינוֹ שָׁוֶה לְקַבֵּל עָלָיו שֶׁבַע מִצְווֹת. וּלְפִי זֶה **צָרְכֵי חוֹלֶה שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ סַכָּנָה, דְּקַיְמָא לָן אוֹמֵר לְעַכּוּ''ם וְעוֹשֶׂה**, וְכֵן מֵת בְּיוֹם טוֹב רִאשׁוֹן דְּקַיְמָא לָן יִתְעַסְקוּ בּוֹ עֲמָמִין, אָסוּר לוֹמַר לְעֶבֶד יִשְׂרָאֵל אֲפִלּוּ הוּא עוֹבֵד עֲבוֹדַת אֱלִילִים, דְּכֵיוָן דִּמְלֶאכֶת הָעֶבֶד אֲסוּרָה מִן הַתּוֹרָה, לֹא הֻתְּרָה בְּדָבָר שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ פִּקּוּחַ נֶפֶשׁ. וְיֵשׁ חוֹלְקִים וּמַתִּירִים בָּזֶה. וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם אִם הָיָה עוֹשֶׂה מְלֶאכֶת רַבּוֹ שֶׁלֹּא מִדַּעְתּוֹ, וְנִכָּר שֶׁאֵינוֹ עוֹשֶׂה לְדַעְתּוֹ, מֻתָּר וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ לְהַפְרִישׁוֹ. אֲפִלּוּ קִבֵּל עָלָיו שֶׁבַע מִצְווֹת. וּלְיִשְׂרָאֵל אַחֵר שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַבּוֹ אֲפִלּוּ עוֹשֶׂה לְדַעַת יִשְׂרָאֵל, מֻתָּר כָּל שֶׁאֵין שָׁם אֲמִירַת יִשְׂרָאֵל. וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא יֵהָנֶה יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּשַׁבָּת מֵאוֹתָהּ מְלָאכָה. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁכָּל שֶׁלֹּא קִבֵּל עָלָיו שֶׁבַע מִצְווֹת בְּנֵי נֹחַ, כֵּיוָן דְּעַכּוּ''ם גָּמוּר הוּא, אֵין רַבּוֹ מֻזְהָר עָלָיו. וּלְפִי זֶה צָרְכֵי חוֹלֶה שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ סַכָּנָה וְכֵן צָרְכֵי מֵתִים בְּיוֹם טוֹב רִאשׁוֹן מֻתָּר לוֹמַר לָהֶם לַעֲשׂוֹתוֹ.‏

**Non-Jewish hired staff** have the same halacha as any other non-Jew and they do not have to keep Shabbat. See 304:3 עַכּוּ''ם גָּמוּר שֶׁהוּא שָׂכִיר אֵין רַבּוֹ מְצֻוֶּה עַל שְׁבִיתָתוֹ‏

So, they may not be asked to do any work for you that you may not do (see the laws of Amira L'Akum for details), with some notable exceptions.

For example:

- For Tzar Ba'alei Chayim, so they may milk your cows (though what to do with the milk is another story).

  - > See 305:20 -  מֻתָּר לוֹמַר לְעַכּוּ''ם  לַחְלֹב בְּהֶמְתּוֹ בְּשַׁבָּת מִשּׁוּם צַעַר בַּעֲלֵי חַיִּים שֶׁהֶחָלָב מְצַעֲרָהּ, וְהֶחָלָב אָסוּר בּוֹ בַּיּוֹם. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁצָּרִיךְ לִקְנוֹתוֹ מִן הָעַכּוּ''ם בְּדָבָר מוּעָט, שֶׁלֹּא יְהֵא נִרְאֶה  כְּחוֹלֵב לְצֹרֶךְ יִשְׂרָאֵל.‏
- They can take care of the ill even if they are not in danger (Chole She'ein bo Sakana).

  - > See 304:1 -  וּלְפִי זֶה צָרְכֵי חוֹלֶה שֶׁאֵין בּוֹ סַכָּנָה, דְּקַיְמָא לָן אוֹמֵר לְעַכּוּ''ם וְעוֹשֶׂה

To answer your question: Your full-time live-in maid may work on Shabbat and does not get a day off. However, she cannot be asked (or expected) to do anything that you are forbidden to do, like cooking.

But she can still look after the kids, set the table and clean up after the meals.